# How to use waversurfer js to stream an audio file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-player, wavesurfer.js

I'm creating a web-app with react js and I would like to use wavesurfer js as music player. Does Wavesurfer js preload audio file? Or does it allow stream ?

here is the code i am using:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from "react";

import wavesurfer from "wavesurfer.js";

const Wave = ({ fileURL }) => {
 
  const [wavesurferObj, setWavesurferObj] = useState();  // crate an instance of the wavesurfer
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(true); // to keep track whether audio is currently playing or not
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(null); // duration is used to set the default region of selection for trimming the audio
  const wavesurferRef = useRef(null);

  // create the waveform inside the correct component
  useEffect(() => {
    if (wavesurferRef.current && !wavesurferObj) {
      setWavesurferObj(
        wavesurfer.create({
          container: "#waveform",
          scrollParent: false,
          autoCenter: true,
          cursorColor: "#30F2DB",
          waveColor: "#71717A",
          progressColor: "#30F2DB",
          responsive: true,
          barWidth:4,
        })
      );
    } else if (wavesurferObj) {
      wavesurferObj.load(fileURL);
      wavesurferObj.on("ready", () => {
        let time=wavesurferObj.getDuration()
        wavesurferObj.play();
        setDuration((time/60).toString().slice(0,4).replace('.',":")); // set the duration in local state
      });

      // once audio starts playing, set the state variable to true
      wavesurferObj.on("play", () => {
        setPlaying(true);
      });

      // once audio starts playing, set the state variable to false
      wavesurferObj.on("finish", () => {
        setPlaying(false);
      });
    }
  }, [wavesurferRef, wavesurferObj]);

  const handlePlayPause = (e) => {
    wavesurferObj.playPause();
    setPlaying(!playing);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={wavesurferRef} id="waveform" style={{marginTop:100}} />
      <div className="all-controls">
        <div className="left-container">
          <button
            title="play/pause"
            className="controls"
            onClick={handlePlayPause}
          >
            {playing ? (
              <i className="material-icons">pause</i>
            ) : (
              <i className="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
        <p>{duration}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Wave;
```

I don't want my app to become too heavy with the preload, can someone tell me if I'm using a stream by doing so?

If not, is there any other alternative? I would prefer wavesurfer because it is possible to change the style and make it similar to soundcloud.

Some have recommended react-audio to me, but I don't like the ui very much